# Como remover as chaves do nível 1 usando somente um método Callback

Tags: php, array, lista, callback

Não quero usar **foreach** e nem **for**.
Por exemplo, eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_usuario] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [idade] => 21
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
         (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_usuario] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [idade] => 15
                )
         )
)
```

Porém gostaria que meu array ficasse assim:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id_usuario] => 1                       
                [idade] => 21
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
               [id_usuario] => 2
               [idade] => 15
            )
    )
```

**Obs:** também não quero nada similar a isso:

```
foreach ($items as list($var1, $var2, $var3)) {
    if ($var1 == $var2) {
        echo $var3;
    }
}
```

O objetivo é melhorar a estrutura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazendo assim:

```
$myarray = array(
            array(
                array('id_usuario' => 1),
                array('idade' => 21)
                ),
            array(
                array('id_usuario' => 2),
                array('idade' => 15)
                )
         );
$data =  array_map(function($arr) {
                 return array_merge($arr[0],$arr[1]);
}, $myarray);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Como não deseja utilizar condições, considerando sua estrutura fixa de array,  `array_merge` resolve, ela funde um ou mais arrays.

```
$teste = Array(
            Array(
                Array('id_usuario' => 1),
                Array('idade' => 21)),
            Array(
                Array('id_usuario' => 2),
                Array('idade' => 15)));

$r[0] = array_merge($teste[0][0], $teste[0][1]);
$r[1] = array_merge($teste[1][0], $teste[1][1]);

print_r($r);
```